# Replacing strings in textile with php

Tags: php, file, str-replace

I have a text file which holds raw svg code. I need to scan this text file and remove all height and width elements from the text file but I'm unsure how I'd do this because I don't know what the height and width values are set to.

```
    $arrFrom = array("width=","height=");
    $arrTo = array(" "," ");

   $newFile = str_replace($arrFrom, $arrTo, $svg);
```

But can I search for the width and height elements and then maybe scan the characters after it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Preg_replace? Have you tried it?

Comment: Or use str_pos to get the start of height/width and then again use str_pos to find the end and remove it with substr. Hard, complex and will make you mad, but it may work

Comment: use preg_replace('string','regex')

Comment: I would use `SimpleXMLElement` to load the SVG file, then loop through the elements and look for the `width` and `height` attributes.